# Retrieving video size using QtGStreamer returns ZERO

Tags: c++, qt4, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I'm playing with **[QtGStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html) 0.10.0** and I'm trying to retrieve the video size but it's returning **ZERO** for **height** and **width** values.

However, **I am able to play the video** with no problems on a *QImage*.

```
QGst::init();        

pipeline = QGst::Pipeline::create();
filesrc = QGst::ElementFactory::make("filesrc");
filesrc->setProperty("location", "sample.avi");
pipeline->add(filesrc);

decodebin = QGst::ElementFactory::make("decodebin2").dynamicCast<QGst::Bin>();
pipeline->add(decodebin);
QGlib::connect(decodebin, "pad-added", this, &MyMultimedia::onNewDecodedPad);
QGlib::connect(decodebin, "pad-removed", this, &MyMultimedia::onRemoveDecodedPad);
filesrc->link(decodebin);

// more code ...
```

The code above shows the begining of the pipeline setup. By connecting my method `MyMultimedia::onNewDecodedPad` on the signal `"pad-added"` I have access to the data of the video. At least that's what I think.

```
void MyMultimedia::onNewDecodedPad(QGst::PadPtr pad)
{  
    QGst::CapsPtr caps = pad->caps();
    QGst::StructurePtr structure = caps->internalStructure(0);
    if (structure->name().contains("video/x-raw"))
    {
        // Trying to print width and height using a couple of different ways,
        // but all of them returns 0 for width/height.

        qDebug() << "#1 Size: " << structure->value("width").get<int>() << "x" << structure->value("height").get<int>();

        qDebug() << "#2 Size: " << structure->value("width").toInt() << "x" << structure->value("height").toInt();

        qDebug() << "#3 Size: " << structure.data()->value("width").get<int>() << "x" << structure.data()->value("height").get<int>();

        // numberOfFields also returns 0, which is very wierd.
        qDebug() << "numberOfFields:" << structure->numberOfFields(); 

    }

    // some other code
}
```

I wonder what I might be doing wrong. Any tips? I was unable to find a relevant example on the web using this API.

Comment: That look similar to gstreamer c examples. You can take a look into those, and maybe you figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved it**. At `onNewDecodedPad()` you still don't have access to information about the video frames.

The class `MyMultimedia` inherits from `QGst::Utils::ApplicationSink`, so I had to implement a method named `QGst::FlowReturn MyMultimedia::newBuffer()` that is called by QtGstreamer whenever a new frame is ready.

In other words, use this method to copy the frame of the video to a `QImage`. What I didn't know is that `pullBuffer()` returns a `QGst::BufferPtr`, which has a `QGst::CapsPtr`. It's an internal structure from this var that holds the information I was looking for:

```
QGst::FlowReturn MyMultimedia::newBuffer()
{
    QGst::BufferPtr buf_ptr = pullBuffer();        
    QGst::CapsPtr caps_ptr = buf_ptr->caps();
    QGst::StructurePtr struct_ptr = caps_ptr->internalStructure(0);

    qDebug() << struct_ptr->value("width").get<int>() << 
                "x" << 
                struct_ptr->value("height").get<int>();

    // ...
}
```